# How to set `.gitignore` so that `../../.aws/` is excluded from `git status` output?

Tags: git

My `.gitignore` file is instructing to ignore the `../../.aws/` directory:

```
$ cat .gitignore
coredumps/
../../.aws/
.*.sw*
*bak
*log
```

Alas, that instruction is ignored:

```
$ git status | head -6
# On branch main
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../../.aws/
#       ../../.bash_history
```

How should I change my `.gitignore` so that the `../../.aws/` will be excluded from the `git status` output?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to exclude something with `.gitignore` that shouldn't be in the scope of the `git` repo in the first place? Where is the root of it located? Add some directory listings to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file applies to the files in the same directory where it is located and its subdirectories. It doesn't apply to parent directories or their other subdirectories. You're trying to ignore `../../.aws/`, which is two directories above where your `.gitignore` file is located.

Here are a few ways to handle this:

1. **Place a `.gitignore` file in the appropriate directory**: If you have the ability to place a `.gitignore` file in the `.aws/` directory or its immediate parent directory, you could do that. In that `.gitignore` file, you would add an entry to ignore the `.aws/` directory.
2. **Use a global `.gitignore` file**: If you want to ignore files like this across all of your Git repositories, you can create a global `.gitignore` file:

   ```bash
   git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'
   ```

   Then you can add `.aws/` to this `~/.gitignore_global` file.

Remember, if files in `.aws/` directory were previously tracked by Git, you need to remove them from the repository before Git starts ignoring them. You can do this without deleting the local copies of the files with the command:

```bash
git rm --cached -r .aws/
```

After running this command, Git will stop tracking the changes in the `.aws/` directory.